# Need to replace value from one file to another file using perl

Tags: perl, replace

I am writing a program using perl which read a value from one file and replace this value in other file. Program runs successfully, but value didn't get replaced. Please suggest me where is the error.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(file1,"address0.txt") or die "Cannot open file.\n";
my $value;
$value=<file1>;
system("perl -p -i.bak -e 's/add/$value/ig' rough.sp");
```

Here the value which I want to replace exists in address0.txt file. It is a single value 1. I want to place this value in place of add in other file rough.sp.

My rough.sp looks like

```
Vdd 1 0 add
```

My address0.txt looks like

```
1
```

So output should be like

```
Vdd 1 0 1
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems somehow dirty to be using a `system` call to exec perl within perl.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a 1:1 relationship between lines in adress0.txt and rough.sp, you can proceed like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($curline_1,$curline_2);
open(file1, "address0.txt") or die "Cannot open file.\n";
open(file2, "rough.sp") or die "Cannot open file.\n";
open(file3, ">out.sp") or die "Cannot open file.\n";

while (<file1>) {
    $curline_1 = $_;
    chomp($curline_1);
    $curline_2 = <file2>;
    $curline_2 =~ s/ add/ $curline_1/;
    print file3 $curline_2;
}
close(file1);
close(file2);
close(file3);
exit(0);
```

Explanation:

The code iterates through the lines of your input files in parallel. Note that the lines read include the line terminator. Line contents from the 'address' file are taken as replacement values fpr the `add` literal in your .sp file. Line terminators from the 'address' file are eliminated to avoid introducing additional newlines.

Addendum:

An extension for multi-replacements might look like this:

```
    $curline_1 = $_;
    chomp($curline_1);

    my @parts = split(/ +/, $curline_1); # splits the line from address0.txt into an array of strings made up of contiguous non-whitespace chars

    $curline_2 = <file2>;
    $curline_2 =~ s/ add/ $parts[0]/;
    $curline_2 =~ s/ sub/ $parts[1]/;
    # ...
```

Comment: Hi collapsar..Thanks...But this code is not working, neither on Linux or Windows. My rough.sp actually contain 100 line program. Anyway I need to ask that variable $curline_1 is getting what values? Is it getting through while loop?

Comment: I've tested it on windows and it works like charm - do you get any error messages? What does the output file look like? Wrt your question: the idiom `while <file1> {...}` reads a file line by line , assigning each line to the variable `$_` as you go. Ps: there was a typo in 'use strict;' - I corrected it, does it work now?

Comment: Yaa its working now. Thanks. What is chomp doing here. Is it removing white spaces in my address0.txt or splitting. Please suggest what if I want multilple replacements. Then my address file would be like array. Then do i need to put multiple scalar variables like $curline_3 $curline_4 and so on...

Comment: `chomp` removes the trailing newline ( to be precise, it removes the 'current record separator' which resides in perl variable `$/`, which in this case just happens to be the 'trailing newline'. nb: by resetting `$/`,you could cater for other kinds of  line terminators). For the skeletal code for multiple replacements, see the addendum in the answer.

Comment: Btw, no offence intended, but mastering perl comes much easier by consulting [the official docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/) on a regular basis - they have reference sections for the language and the core module and several tutorials covering important topics like oo or regexen at different levels of detail. The site also differentiates by perl version.